# Statistics of single questions

Tags: discussion, asking-questions, statistics

We have at the moment c. 940,000 questions at MSE. 
Some users have access to statistics of the site.

I'm interested in the issue:

How many questions were asked by one-question users? (users who asked only one question)

Comment: "Some users have access to statistics of the site." That's not covered there. You also have access to statistics via the "data explorer." Chances are there is a query available there, if not you could write it.

Comment: I will add to quid's comment that links to some basic information about data explorer (a.k.a. SEDE) can be found in the [corresponding tag-info](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/tags/data-explorer/info).

Comment: Today members  have c. 550 000 number, and we have 940,000 questions. I infer that majority of questions are asked by one-question  askers unless there are a vast number of deleted questions, also unknown to me.. it would be interesting to know the numbers..

Comment: One complicating factor is that some users, who have asked only one question, come back, registered for/created a new account (sometimes multiple times), and asked handfuls of questions, each of which is asked one user/one current account, at a time.  So say, user repeat#13-new-user, may each time post one question, but has actually asked 13 separate questions by cycling through "new user" accounts..  So do we can this user as posting 13 questions, or do we count this as 13 user accounts posting one question each?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

SEDE returned [115626 users with exactly one question](http://data.stackexchange.com/math/query/844693/users-with-1-question). The query was

```
select count(a.uid) from (
  select OwnerUserId as uid from Posts
    where PostTypeId = 1
    group by OwnerUserId
    having count(Id) = 1
) a
```

I imagine a large number of such questions are deleted, but those cannot be counted. Even if one uses the table PostsWithDeleted instead of table Posts, this does not help because the rows for deleted posts do not have OwnerUserId filled.

Comment: That's a little surprising. I thought  the number is higher..

Comment: For 2 questions it returned 27881, for 3 questions 13279,   for 0 it returns ... 0 (maybe 0 is not available for the program)

Comment: What about 1 question, no answer? I took the question to be about these even though it is not what is written.

Comment: @quid [107536](http://data.stackexchange.com/math/query/844744/users-with-one-question-and-no-answers) of those.

Comment: @Widawensen Yes, 0  does not fit the logic of group / having, as a group cannot have 0 elements. Another query shows [207930](http://data.stackexchange.com/math/query/844747/users-with-zero-questions) users with no posts at all, and [234859](http://data.stackexchange.com/math/query/844750/users-with-no-questions) users with no questions.

Comment: @bro You are a really master of the site statistics, thank you very much for all these results.. it gives some picture of the vast site graph, maybe the results can be used somehow in the modeling of this graph ..